# How to do a masked query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, masking

For example, I am storing user passports in Elasticsearch. They are stored as consecutive letters and digits of the following format: `AADDDDDDD`. 2 alphabet and then 7 digits.

User is interested in search where he could mention specific values for specific positions. For example, I want to search all the passport numbers who have 'A' at the beginning, '7' in the third position and '0' in the last position. Something like this:

```
A-7----0
```

How to generate an efficient query for this? Do I need to create any custom analyzer for this?

So far what I've done is I inserted space in between characters and then searching for index position, seems like a costly operation to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much efficient query do you need? If your data is not very big you can try regexp query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Other suggest will be use document with array of symbols and their places. ex.

```
   {
        'code' : [
           {'pos':1, 'symbol':A},{'pos':2, 'symbol':B}, ...
        ]
    }
```

then you can use a bool filter, and efficiently use filter cache

Comment: There are good number of documents / records. But each string will be small. Like less than 16 characters.

Comment: Then I suggest try second solution. It should work pretty well

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on the 2nd way? What type of search is this? Are these term filter? I could not find anything that deal with 'pos' and 'symbol'.